# How to wrapping around STL containers and get proper const and non-const behavior?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, constants

When wrapping a container type e.g. `std::vector< T >` where `T` is a smart-pointer type e.g. `std::shared_ptr< SomeType >`, is there a way to simultaneously ensure *const correctness* and enable iterator *const* overloads in a simple fashion?

For instance, off the following snippet:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


class SomeType {
 public:
    using Ptr = std::shared_ptr< SomeType >;
    using ConstPtr = std::shared_ptr< const SomeType >;
    // ...

    SomeType(double v) : value(v) { /* ... */ }


    double value;
    // ...
};


class MyContainerWrapper {
 public:
    using Container = std::vector< SomeType::Ptr >;
    // ...

    MyContainerWrapper(size_t size) : _data(size, SomeType::Ptr(new SomeType(1.23))) { /* ... */ }
    // ...

    void add(double v) { _data.emplace_back(new SomeType(v) ); }
    // ...

    // being/end iterators (e.g. range-based loop)
    typename Container::iterator begin() { printf("b\n"); return _data.begin(); };
    typename Container::iterator end() { printf("e\n"); return _data.end(); };
    // const overloads
    typename Container::const_iterator begin() const { printf("cb\n"); return _data.begin(); };     // pointer to non-const (!)
    typename Container::const_iterator end() const { printf("ce\n"); return _data.end(); };         // pointer to non-const (!)

 protected:
    Container _data;
};



void modifier(const MyContainerWrapper& arg) {
    for (const auto& element : arg) {
        // ...
        element->value = 12.345;   // how to avoid this being possible (?)
    }
}



int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    MyContainerWrapper cont(10);

    modifier(cont);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to design the `begin()` and `end()` *const* overloads in `MyContainerWrapper` without having to either 1) write a custom iterator type, or even (much less efficient) 2) storing a duplicate container with `SomeType::ConstPtr` isntances?

Comment: I believe that you're actually running into a design flaw in `std::shared_ptr`. I never liked shared_ptr's design. I roll my own, with both a ptr and a const_ptr, mirroring the design of iterator and const_iterator, and dereferencing a const ptr results in a const object. This is const-correct, and shared_ptr is broken.

Comment: Sounds like you want [`propogate_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const)?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've actually written a small iterator class that works around this issue, but yeah, the issue lies with `std::shared_ptr` implementation.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: How is shallow const not appropriate for `std::shared_ptr`?  It has stronger pointer semantics than `std::unique_ptr` since the whole point of it is to create multiple references to the same object—and if you did so with `for (auto element : arg)` you’d be able to write through the copy anyway.

Comment: So you want to promise, @DavisHerring, that your function will not modify the referenced `Foo`? So you declare its parameter as `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>`. Great! Now every function call requires a construction and a destruction of a temporary, and screwing around with a reference count, instead of merely tossing a reference to a `const_shared_ptr` over the wall. And don't get me started on the fact that `std::shared_ptr` is really two pointers instead of just one...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Declaring the parameter as `const nonstd::shared_propagate_const_ptr<Foo>` wouldn't actually promise anything thanks to the copying issue (although I have done exactly this to emulate "smart references" before).  If all you want is to not modify the `Foo`, you just accept a `const Foo&`; if you also need to manipulate the `Foo`'s lifetime, it's only reasonable to "copy" into a `std::shared_ptr<const Foo>` that then enforces the constness on all descendants of that copy.